# Perl - searching for partial matches in string array and returning matching indices

Tags: arrays, string, perl, indices

Suppose I have a string array `@file_paths` which contains

```
@file_paths= ["C:\Lazy\FolderA\test.cpp", "C:\Lazy\FolderA\test2.cpp", 
              "C:\Lazy\FolderB\test.cpp", "C:\Lazy\FolderB\test2.cpp", ... etc]
```

I want to be able to find the array indices corresponding to the FolderA positions, FolderB, positions.. and so on.

i.e something like `@file_paths.indices("FolderA")` would return `@indices = [0,1]`
              and `@file_paths.indices("FolderB")` would return `@indices = [2,3]`.. etc

The trick is I'd be doing a contains function on @file_paths to get the corresponding indices. What would the subroutine look like?

Comment: This doesn't look like Perl code -- initializing an array using a list in square brackets, unescaped backslashes inside double-quoted strings, dot-notation on an array, etc. What am I missing?

Comment: "What would the subroutine look like?" - That's not how it works. You show us what you've tried, and "we" help with your problem.

Comment: I'm using suedo-Perl notation..

Comment: @user1022944: I don't think they make an interpreter for that variant. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer: http://bit.ly/13LE8K0

you can use CPAN [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aMoreUtils)

```
use 5.012;
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw(indexes);

my @file_paths= qw(
        C:\Lazy\FolderA\test.cpp C:\Lazy\FolderA\test2.cpp
        C:\Lazy\FolderB\test.cpp C:\Lazy\FolderB\test2.cpp
);

my @ind = indexes {$_ =~ /FolderB/} @file_paths;
say "@ind";
```

says

```
2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my @file_paths= ("C:\\Lazy\\FolderA\\test.cpp", "C:\\Lazy\\FolderA\\test2.cpp", 
              "C:\\Lazy\\FolderB\\test.cpp", "C:\\Lazy\\FolderB\\test2.cpp");

my @aIndices = indices("FolderA", @file_paths);


sub indices {
  my ($keyword, @paths) = @_;
  my @results = ();

  for ( my $i = 0; $i < @paths; ++$i )
  {
    if ($paths[$i] =~ /\\$keyword\\/)
    {
      push @results, $i;
    }
  }

  return @results;
}
```